# Swift 3: Not able to store Token value in another String

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
 let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
```

need to get FCM token: (token ?? "") in another variable.

Comment: do you mean you need some variable with string value of `FCM token: tokenString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Messaging.messaging().fcmToken` line return nil or empty string. **If it is an optional** then you can check using `if let or guard statement` to get more idea.

```
if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
} else {
   print("It is empty")
}
```

or

```
 guard let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken else { return }
 print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
```